# Update query doesnt work on cassandra cqlsh

Tags: cassandra, cql, cqlsh

When I select following query, it returns this record:

```
cqlsh:my_keyspace> select status from my_devices where deviceid='ffffffff-b897-c010-0000-xxx43' ;

status
--------
  4
```

But when I tried exactly the same where clause in update cql, it doesnt affect the row.

```
cqlsh:my_keyspace> update my_devices set status=1 where deviceid='ffffffff-b897-c010-0000-xxx43';
cqlsh:subscriber_data_keyspace>
```

What could be the cause of this issue?

Comment: What does your table definition look like?  Also, try running both the SELECT and UPDATE queries with tracing on, and see if that reveals any clues.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a consistency issue. You can change the consistency level of cqlsh with command `CONSISTENCY level`. I suggest you use `QUORUM`.

For more information about consistency read [this](http://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/dml/dml_config_consistency_c.html).